# Impersonate a user when using ion auth in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have setup ion auth to store session information in the database. The ci_session table has the following fields

> id   ,ip_address     ,timestamp  ,data

I can fetch the data of my current session with this code

```
$this->db->order_by('id', 'ASC');
$this->db->limit(1);
$last_session = $this->db->get('ci_sessions')->row_array();

print_r($last_session['data']);//prints current session data
```

I want to be able to switch the logged in user on the fly and for that i have borrowed this function from this gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4440000

which i have modified this way

```
 public function impersonate()
    {
        $identity = 'admin@admin.com';
        $goall = $this->config->item('identity', 'ion_auth');

            $query = $this->db->select($goall . ', username, email, id, active, last_login')
                ->where($goall, $this->db->escape_str($identity))
                ->limit(1)
                ->get('users');

            if ($query->num_rows() === 1)
            {
                $user = $query->row();

                $session_data = array(
                    'identity'             => $goall,
                    'username'             => $user->username,
                    'email'                => $user->email,
                    'user_id'              => $user->id, //everyone likes to overwrite id so we'll use user_id
                    'impersonating'        => true
                );

                $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);

                return TRUE;
            }

         else {

            return FALSE;

        }

    }
```

The data column in ci_sessions looks like this

```
__ci_last_regenerate|i:1491200360;identity|s:15:"admin@admin.com";email|s:15:"admin@admin.com";user_id|s:1:"1";old_last_login|s:10:"1491199371";last_check|i:1491200371;message|s:29:"<p>Logged In Successfully</p>";__ci_vars|a:1:{s:7:"message";s:3:"old";}
```

To be able to switch user, i want to update the data column to reflect the details of the new user.

I tried json decoding the data column data but its not valid json. You can too using this tool http://freeonlinetools24.com/json-decode

How can i update the data field inroder to be able to switch the user logged in?.

Answer (score 0):

That's a horrible, really horrible solution. You should not ever need to decode another user's session data; I suggest you find another way to achieve whatever it is that you're trying to do.